# Z3 variable name causing "unknown" satisfiability

Tags: z3

Using Z3 to check the satisfiability of

```
(declare-fun length ((Array Int Int)) Int)

(declare-const lindx2 (Array Int Int))
(declare-const findx1 (Array Int Int))
(declare-const orig_findx1 (Array Int Int))

(assert (and
  (forall ((i Int) (j Int))
    (let ((a!1 (and (<= 0 i)
                    (<= i (- (length findx1) 1))
                    (<= 0 j)
                    (<= j (- (length orig_findx1) 1))
                    (= i j))))
      (=> a!1 (= (select findx1 i) (select orig_findx1 j)))))
  (= (length lindx2) 11)
  (forall ((i Int)) (=> (and (<= 3 i) (<= i 25)) (= (select findx1 i) (- 1))))))
(check-sat)
```

returns unknown. This essentially tries to assert that all elements in findx1 and orig_findx1 are equal, that length(lindx2)=11, and that findx1[i]=-1 for i=[3,25]. However, changing "findx1" to "indx1" allows Z3 to return satisfiable. Does anyone know what might be causing the unknown satisfiability? I am using Z3 version 4.8.8 on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate this, and it is really bizarre!

I'm not surprised this benchmark is `unknown` since it's full of quantifiers and it'd be hard to solve for z3. But changing `findx1` to `indx1` should have no impact on this; i.e., it should remain `unknown`.

I've reported this at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/4600. The response is: *It is MBQI that ends up failing to determine satisfiability. It is tied to array models. MBQI is more stable when you replace arrays by uninterpreted functions.* That is, these sorts of discrepancies are unfortunately par for the course. Too bad!

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately (albeit for technical reasons) not surprising: it has been observed many times before that syntactic changes (renaming symbols, reordering SMT commands) cause performance and unknown/sat fluctuations, see e.g. https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/909/. It seems that Z3's heuristics are affected by the program structure, even when explicitly setting random seeds.

Comment: I remember seeing many cases of this where performance was impacted indeed.(i.e., slow/fast.) But in this case, an `unknown` answer becomes `sat` and vice-versa. I don't think I've ever seen this, which makes it very dubious. Very unfortunate behavior.

Comment: I've observed many such sat/unknown fluctuations over the years, but also can't find a matching issue right now. I'm pretty sure the root cause is the same as in the performance case, though.